# Multiple RadioButton can be selected in a RadioGroup android

Tags: android, dynamic, view, radio-button

I'm adding programatically (obliged as the number of radiogroup and radiobuttons are variables) radiogroups in my activity layout like that :

```
rg = new RadioGroup(this);
rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
rg.setId(list_questions.get(i).getQuizz_questions_id()); // get from the DB
lrg.add(rg);
for (int j = 0; j < list_answers.size(); j++) {
    rb = new RadioButton(this);
    rb.setId(list_answers.get(j).getQuizz_answers_id());
    rb.setText(String.valueOf(list_answers.get(j).getQuizz_answers_id()) + "-" + String.valueOf(list_answers.size()) + "-" + String.valueOf(list_questions.get(i).getQuizz_questions_id())); // I added that to see if there was a problem on the indexes, but there's not
    rg.addView(rb, new LayoutParams(100,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
tr.addView(rg, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Complete code can be found here : http://pastebin.com/d9zZjmuu

My problem is that I can select two radiobuttons inside three radiogroup.

I know that it'll be difficult for you to help as you don't have all the sources etc. but I am searching what's the problem since two days and didn't find anything so if you can just tell me if you have any idea of where the problem can come from it will be really appreciated !

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: "there was no screenshot app on the device so..." While your image works, the Device window in Eclipse can take screenshots. Next time. :)

Comment: I'm not emulating the app but watching it directly on a tablet that I can't connect to the internet. But thanks still. ;)

Comment: @Arlem post your complete code where you are populating all the radiogroups, it is hard identify based on the information you've provided

Comment: You can take screenshots on devices as well, as long as debugging is enabled. (No root permissions or internet required.)

Comment: @Pragnani : See my edit, I added a pastebin link to my full code, but the part where I'm populating the RadioGroup and RadioButton is just the part that was already posted.

Comment: @Sam : I'll do that next time, thanks.

Comment: You are creating a new RadioButton with the same reference, try take them inside for loop some thing like this  RadioButton  rb = new RadioButton(this);

Comment: Weird. I recreated your problem, can you select multiple RadioButtons in the first row or last two rows? For me, this quirk only happen in the other rows...

Comment: There's already RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);  inside for loop, this is the new RadioGroup(this) which is outside.

Comment: @Sam : Nop I can't, that's exactly where the problem is and why I can't find the source of it... I'm in a way happy that the problem is recreated by others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recreated your problem and solved it by giving each RadioButton a unique id, something simple like:

```
rb.setId(list_answers.get(j).getQuizz_answers_id() + i * list_questions.size());
```

I'm not sure *why* the default OnCheckedChangeListeners are getting confused at this moment, but here's an easy fix.

Comment: Thanks but here's another problem, each RadioButton ID corresponds to a "response" field in the DB (on the screenshot "Réalisé partiellement", "Jamais réalisé" ...) and I need to get them to fill the DB with the user's answers like that :
    for (RadioGroup bla : lrg) {
     useranswers.insert(new user_answers(null, ApplicationHelper.getInstance().idUser, ApplicationHelper.getInstance().idSession, bla.getId(), bla.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
    }

So I can't set them randomly as you do.

Comment: Actually these ids aren't random, you convert them into `list_answers.get(j).getQuizz_answers_id()` (i.e. 5, 6, 7) with modulo. Try `bla.getCheckedRadioButtonId() % list_questions.size()`

Comment: that's not random. you just have to make a modulo to get the value

Comment: Shouldn't I take the "+ i" out if I want to get back to the same value using "% list_questions.size()" ? Or I'm missing something...

Comment: @Arlem Nope, [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is not division. For instance, `(j + i * size) % size` will always equal j. Modulo is the remainder after division.

Comment: I tried with rb.setId(list_answers.get(j).getQuizz_answers_id()*2) and then bla.getCheckedRadioButtonId()/2 and it seems to work too... I really don't know from where the problem came from. Thanks Sam and all the others who took time to think about my problem !